Indicate several curl options via httr::config(ssl_options = c(LIST OF SEVERAL CURLSSLOPT_) )
How to pass several libcurl options via httr::config(ssl_options = ...), please ?
My primary goal is to indicate these 2 arguments : CURLSSLOPT_AUTO_CLIENT_CERT and CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA, in order to rely on the schannel default behavior for establishing a ssl double-auth.
Thanks a lot for any tips and advices.
✅ For example the following will enable schannel correctly and ssl try to rely on local client-cert' :
urll = "https://www.google.com"
    
response <- httr::GET(
        urll,
        httr::config(use_ssl = T ,followlocation = T
             ,  ssl_options = c("CURLSSLOPT_AUTO_CLIENT_CERT"=32)
                , verbose = T ) )

According to the log, the session is able to use client-certificate (i.e. logs indicate that * schannel: enabled automatic use of client certificate)
But I can't figure out how I'm supposed to pass several "ssl_options" ?
❌ The here-after example will result in an error :
         response <- httr::GET(
                urll,
                httr::config(use_ssl = T ,followlocation = T
                     ,  ssl_options = c("CURLSSLOPT_AUTO_CLIENT_CERT"=32 
                                      , "CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA" = 16)  
                        , verbose = T ) )

    Error: curl::handle_setopt(handle, .list = req$options) : 
      Value for option ssl_options (216) must be a number.

Any way to indicate to libcurl several "ssl_options" with httr::config(ssl_options = [??]) ?

According to
httr::curl_docs("ssl_options")
#> Please point your browser to the following url:
#> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS.html

it's a bitmask, you could try bitwOr()or simply adding relevant symbols -
curl::curl_symbols("CURLSSLOPT_")
#>                               name introduced deprecated removed value type
#> 1005        CURLSSLOPT_ALLOW_BEAST     7.25.0       <NA>    <NA>     1 <NA>
#> 1006   CURLSSLOPT_AUTO_CLIENT_CERT     7.77.0       <NA>    <NA>    32 <NA>
#> 1007          CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA     7.71.0       <NA>    <NA>    16 <NA>
#> 1008    CURLSSLOPT_NO_PARTIALCHAIN     7.68.0       <NA>    <NA>     4 <NA>
#> 1009          CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE     7.44.0       <NA>    <NA>     2 <NA>
#> 1010 CURLSSLOPT_REVOKE_BEST_EFFORT     7.70.0       <NA>    <NA>     8 <NA>

- to set bits:
httr_cfg <- 
  httr::config(
    use_ssl = TRUE,
    followlocation = TRUE,
    verbose = TRUE,
    ssl_options = 
      curl::curl_symbols("CURLSSLOPT_AUTO_CLIENT_CERT")$value +
      curl::curl_symbols("CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA")$value
  )

httr_cfg
#> <request>
#> Options:
#> * use_ssl: TRUE
#> * followlocation: TRUE
#> * verbose: TRUE
#> * ssl_options: 48

urll = "https://www.google.com"
response <- httr::GET(urll, httr_cfg)

Created on 2024-12-11 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks a lot for indicating the syntax for passing ssl_options via httr, within R (i.e. the accepted answer defines  ssl_options = 32 + 16 for passing 2 parameters). Please, there is some limitation outside of "passing legit CURLSSLOPT bitcodes" ? Or there is special consideration to have when using this  precise way of passing parameters ? (for example, I have the posibility to specify more than 2 options safely or this will lead in a confusion for the curl SSL engine ?)
Thanks a lot for the answer and code-sample @margusl :)

You can combine all CURLSSLOPT_ , values safely by just summing. Each of those 6 values have only a single unique bit set (1 = b00000001, 2 =  b00000010, ... , 32 = b00100000), so the final ssl_options can be decoded as a set of options, i.e. 32 + 16  + 2 + 1 = b00110011
